# Problems with 'scoreItems' function in R

Tags: r, average, reverse

I am trying to clean my data set that requires reverse coding followed by calculating the average of four items to accurately measure a facet (for a personality questionnaire). My data is called 'hex_data' and here is what I have thus far except I keep getting the following warning code:

```
'Error in 1:nkeys : argument of length 0.'
```

Here are the following combinations of code that I have tried to run:

```
hex_data_rev <- reverse.code(keys = c(1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1), items = hex_data, mini = NULL, maxi = NULL)

hsinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = c(1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1), items = hex_data, totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = rep(1,1351), max = rep(676,1351))
hsinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = rep(1,1351), items = hex_data_rev, totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = rep(1,10), max = rep(6,10))


hscinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = c(1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1), items = hex_data_rev, totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = NULL, max = NULL)
hscinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = c(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1), items = hex_data_rev, totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = NULL, max = NULL)
hscinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = c(1,1), items = hex_data_rev[c(1:4)], totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = NULL, max = NULL)
hscinc_score <- scoreItems(keys = rep(1,10), items = hex_data_rev, totals = FALSE, missing = TRUE, impute = "none", min = NULL, max = NULL)
```

PLEASE help me/ask questions if this doesn't make sense

Comment: OK. You are going to have to tell people which of the thousands of R packages `scoreItems` and `reverse.code` come from? Then someone might be able to help.

Comment: @StephenHenderson sorry for the confusion - these commands belong to the psych() package

Answer (score 0):

I believe the keys argument should be a matrix. You can also pass a `keys.list` argument to the `scoreItems()` function. I had submitted a vector of keys instead of specifying a list and got the very same error message you got.

Passing a list for `keys.list` solved it.

```
# vector (wrong)
keys.list <- c(
    is = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"), 
    cm = c("q5", "q6", "q7", "q8"),
    se = c( "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12"),
    tot = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", 
          "q12"))

# list (right)
keys.list <- list(
    is = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"), 
    cm = c("q5", "q6", "q7", "q8"),
    se = c( "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12"),
    tot = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", 
          "q12"))

prescores <- scoreItems(keys.list, pre[,2:13], totals = FALSE)
```